# How to Access Spark PipelineModel Parameters

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

I am running a linear regression using [Spark Pipelines](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-pipeline.html#ml-pipelines) in pyspark.  Once the linear regression model is trained, how do I get the coefficients out?

Here is my pipeline code:

```
# Get all of our features together into one array called "features".  Do not include the label!
feature_assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=get_column_names(df_train), outputCol="features")

# Define our model
lr = LinearRegression(maxIter=100, elasticNetParam=0.80, labelCol="label", featuresCol="features", 
                  predictionCol = "prediction")

# Define our pipeline
pipeline_baseline = Pipeline(stages=[feature_assembler, lr])

# Train our model using the training data
model_baseline = pipeline_baseline.fit(df_train)

# Use our trained model to make predictions using the validation data
output_baseline = model_baseline.transform(df_val)  #.select("features", "label", "prediction", "coefficients")
predictions_baseline = output_baseline.select("label", "prediction")
```

I have tried using methods from the [PipelineModel class](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=pipeline#pyspark.ml.PipelineModel).  Here are my attempts to get the coefficients, but I only get an empty list and an empty dictionary:

```
params = model_baseline.stages[1].params
print 'Try 1 - Parameters: %s' %(params)
params = model_baseline.stages[1].extractParamMap()
print 'Try 2 - Parameters: %s' %(params)

Out[]:
Try 1 - Parameters: []
Try 2 - Parameters: {}
```

Are there methods for PipelineModel that return the trained coefficients?

Answer (score 8):

You are looking at the wrong property. `params` can be used to extract `Estimator` or `Transformer` `Params` like input or output columns (see [ML Pipeline parameters docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-pipeline.html#parameters) and not estimated values.

For `LinearRegressionModel` use `coefficients`:

```
model.stages[-1].coefficients
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Do you also know how I can get the hyper-parameter values out (e.g. regParam or elasticNetParam)?  This is a new application.  I am running a [CrossValidator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=crossvalidator#pyspark.ml.tuning.CrossValidator) instance to try different hyper-parameters.  Once the best model is found, I want to know which hyper-parameters are used by the best model.  `model.bestModel.stages[-1].coefficients` gets me the coefficients of the best linear regression model.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I get: `TypeError: 'Param' object does not support indexing`

Comment: If you are looking at the pipeline, use `pipeline.getStages[-1]`, if you are dealing with a model, use `model.stages[-1]`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38664620/any-way-to-access-methods-from-individual-stages-in-pyspark-pipelinemodel

Comment: is there any way to do this without relying indexing?  what if the model you want coefficients for isn't in the [-1] position?  (maybe you want to put an evaluator after it)